# CGAffineTransform: How to calculate multiply CGAffineTransform?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I need transform view from origin(250, 250) to origin(352, 315), and width/height change from (100.0, 100.0) to (68, 68). 
I know I can combine several CGAffineTransform function together, such as scale, rotate, translate.
But i don't know how to count the order of those transformations, and the exact parameter of them.
I have try several time, but can't move the view to correct position.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A little understanding about what is happening behind the scenes is always nice in these matrix transformations.

Apple docs has a [great documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101) about transforms, so let's use it.

---

A *translation* matrix looks like :

```
|  1   0   0  |
|  0   1   0  |
|  tx  ty  1  |
```

where `(tx, ty)` is your translation vector.

---

A *scaling* matrix looks like :

```
|  sx  0   0  |
|  0   sy  0  |
|  0   0   1  |
```

where `sx`and `sy` are the scale factor in the X and Y axis.

---

You want to concatenate these matrix using `CGAffineTransformConcat`, but as according to [its doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformConcat) :

> Note that matrix operations are not commutative—the order in which you
>   concatenate matrices is important. That is, the result of multiplying
>   matrix t1 by matrix t2 does not necessarily equal the result of
>   multiplying matrix t2 by matrix t1.

You have to translate your view before scaling it, otherwise your translation vector will be scaled according to `sx` and `sy` coefficients.

Let's show it easily :

```
let scaleMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.68, 0.68)
let translateMatrix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(102, 65)

let translateThenScaleMatrix = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleMatrix, translateMatrix)
NSLog("translateThenScaleMatrix : \(translateThenScaleMatrix)")
// outputs : CGAffineTransform(a: 0.68, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 0.68, tx: 102.0, ty: 65.0)
// the translation is the same

let scaleThenTranslateMatrix = CGAffineTransformConcat(translateMatrix, scaleMatrix)
NSLog("scaleThenTranslateMatrix : \(scaleThenTranslateMatrix)")
// outputs : CGAffineTransform(a: 0.68, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 0.68, tx: 69.36, ty: 44.2)
// the translation has been scaled too
```

---

And let's prove it mathematically. Please note that when you perform an operation A then an operation B, the related matrix is computed by doing matB*matA, the first operation is on the right. Since multiplication is not commutative for matrix, it's important.

```
// Translate then  scaling :
|  sx  0   0  |   |  1   0   0  |   |    sx   0    0 |
|  0   sy  0  | . |  0   1   0  | = |    0    sy   0 |
|  0   0   1  |   |  tx  ty  1  |   |    tx   ty   1 |
// The resulting matrix has the same value for translation

// Scaling then translation :
|  1   0   0  |   |  sx  0   0  |   |    sx     0      0 |
|  0   1   0  | . |  0   sy  0  | = |    0      sy     0 |
|  tx  ty  1  |   |  0   0   1  |   |  sx.tx   sy.ty   1 |
// The translation values are affected by scaling coefficient
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now my issue turn to a 4 matrix(identity, translate, scale, rotate) calculate.

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101

Comment: Isn't it totally wrong? If you go to the definition of CGAffineTransformConcat(A,B) in Xcode, it says the resulting transformation matrix is precisely T=A*B. So A is applied first and then B, because p_new = p * T = (p * A)*B - where p is a point. Try to rotate and then translate by applying CGaffinetransformconcat(rotateMatrix, translateMatrix). The object will be rotated in its coordinate frame, and then translation will happen in its coordinate frame.

Comment: Btw, I'm not saying the end result you explained is wrong - what's wrong is the explanation of how it is done internally, and even many books have problems with it.

Comment: When you use a transformation matrix on a point, the transformation matrix is the left operand, so in fact you have pNew = T * p = A * B * p, thus the first transform applied on p is B.

Comment: See the 'The Math Behind the Matrices' part [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101). For me it's clear the point is multiplied on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct CGAffineTransform {
  CGFloat a, b, c, d;
  CGFloat tx, ty;
};
```

You can get parameters by this struct.And transforms always override,in another words,they won't superpose,pay attention to this.